# remote: true option is not working with file field in rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I am trying to submit form via ajax using remote:true option which contains input fields as well as file fields (need to upload images)

Here is my view

```
= form_tag("/campaigns/upload_form", method: 'post', format: :js, enctype: 'multipart/form-data', remote: true) do
```

which contains file field

```
= file_field :campaign, :fb_photo, class: 'form-control', id: 'fb_campaign_product_photo', title: 'Upload Image for your Product'
```

In controller action

```
def upload_form
    # do some stuff
    respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.js
    end
  end
```

When I submit form without file field it is processing and rendering as JS correctly

```
Started POST "/campaigns/upload_form" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-21 18:06:51 +0530
Processing by CampaignsController#upload_form as JS
```

but when I am trying to submit file fields, it is processing as HTML and throwing template missing error as I haven't added view for that.

Editing this post to tell that:
I have tried remotipart gem as suggested in below answer and it worked for me but still getting following error in browser console

```
jquery.js?body=1:9665 POST http://localhost:3000/campaigns/upload_form 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

and getting following error in development.log

```
 ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template campaigns/upload_form, application/upload_form with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/tudip/Documents/cpx/app/views"
  * "/home/tudip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.0/app/views"
  * "/home/tudip/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/devise-9568e28d663e/app/views"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376304/remote-true-not-working-when-a-file-uploader-is-used-in-form

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`remote: true` does not work with multipart/file upload.

You can use **remotipart gem** for this.

https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart/blob/master/README.rdoc

Comment: I tried remotipart gem and it solved my problem but still I am getting missing template error in log file and also on browsers console.

Comment: @MaheshwarKhond  Do you have corresponding template i.e campaigns/upload_form.js.erb ?

Comment: @ dkp Yes I have corresponding template upload_form.js.erb and solution is also working for me. Only problem is still Errors are logged in console as well as in development .log file

Comment: I am able to upload image on production too but when I upload two images simultaneously It is not working

Answer (score -1):

You're using `form_tag` instead of `form_for`. So, use [file_field_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/file_field_tag) instead of `file_field`.

Comment: I have tried file_field_tag but still I am getting missing template error

Comment: Please see @dkp comment asking whether you have upload_form.js.erb - I believe that's the correct next question.

Comment: @ jvillian Yes I have corresponding template upload_form.js.erb and solution is also working for me. Only problem is still Errors are logged in console as well as in development .log file