# Rails: Process form with CarrierWave as JS and not HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, simple-form

I have a simple form that also adds a file to CarrierWave.

```
<%= simple_form_for @person, url: { controller: 'posts', action: 'create'}, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :image_name do |i| %>
    <%= i.input :file %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="form-actions">
     <%= f.submit "Add New Person" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The images are mounted in `PersonImages < ActiveRecord::Base`

In `PersonController` I have

```
def new
  @person = Person.new
  @person.build_person_image
end
```

and..

```
def create
  @person = Person.new(person_params)

  if @ship.save
    @persons = Person.all
    render :person_list and return
  end
end
```

If I only enter a name for the person name field and submit it works.
Note the remote request.
    Console: `Processing by PersonController#create as JS`

The person list partial is rendered.

But if I also add an image file it fails.
Note the rest is no longer a remote one.

```
Console: `Processing by PersonController#create as HTML`
```

The image is uploaded, processed and persisted successfully however Rails now wants to render a `persons/create` html template and not the `persons/create.js.erb` template.

Any ideas?

Comment: After you create a person with image in `create` action, you're trying to take him to index page and list all the `persons` ?

Comment: This answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33564725/359736 should help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [:remote => true not working when a file uploader is used in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376304/remote-true-not-working-when-a-file-uploader-is-used-in-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for only responding now. I did try all the above suggested solutions with no luck. Turns out requests where being made twice.
The solution was to swap out the `jquery_ujs` for `rails-ujs` aand all is well now.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44057260/5268472